# Can't see children components in react props

Tags: reactjs

If I import component-1 to another component-2 and console log component-2, I can't see (in React DOM) Node with component-1. I see only type - function and some props I sent in component-1.

What do I need to do to get React DOM with children (import) components (not function types) in the console log?

[image]

https://codesandbox.io/s/compassionate-robinson-1x3w8?file=/src/App.js

Comment: What do you want to see?

Answer (score 0):

What are you trying to do exactly and what are you expecting?

To me, everything is working as expected; you log out the component instance and you see `props.children` has two children, the `<i>` tag and the array of `<Block>` elements, in Javascript representation.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Don't make it complicated. If they are shown in DOM, I think you can use a directive descendant CSS selector to query all your child nodes. For example: `document.querySelectorAll("div.parent-component > div:child-component")`